# How should NPM deprecation warnings be treated?

Tags: npm, npm-install

Whenever using npm install, I usually get at least one deprecation warning for one of the packages being used. This never seems to create any issues from what I can tell, but ignoring warnings feels like a poor move as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not depending directly on the deprecated packages, you're probably not accomplishing anything by installing them directly. Whichever package depends on it is the one that needs to update its dependencies, and so on until you reach the package you're developing. Essentially: if it's important (e.g. a security problem), notify the package maintainers; if not, ignore the deprecation warning.